# Deactive row instead of deleting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I want to inactivate rows instead of deleting them.

My current Code deletes the character. Instead I want to set column IsActive to 0 (false)

```
 [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            Character character = db.Characters.Find(id);
            db.Characters.Remove(character);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Table Definition:

```
CharacterID int 
isActive    bit 
UserId  uniqueidentifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {            
        Character character = db.Characters.Find(id);
        character.isActive = false;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

If you used a generated .edmx, isActive should be set to a boolean.

Comment: you need to change: character.IsActive = false;